# functions on nested dataframes from R to python

Tags: python, r, pandas, tidyverse

Recently I have become addicted to the following pattern in R tidyverse:

```
mtcars %>%
as_tibble() %>%
tidyr::nest(-carb) %>%
mutate(data = purrr::map(data, function(x){
do_something_to_data
}))
```

I tend to use it quite often to create nested dataframes depending on a variable (carb in this example) and to mutate the nested data (e.g. adding a new column or transforming an existing one).

I am curious about what would be the best way to achieve the same goal in python + pandas. Does pandas support nested dataframes, and if not, what would be the best data structure to emulate what R does here?